# How to change the color of indicator value in Trading View?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

[image]
this is the default upColor for the green indicator (left of picture)

However i want to change it to a different color (for example white).

I have tried

`"mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.upColor": "white",`

but it only changed the candlecolors not the indicator values color.